# How can i delete space from text file and replace it semicolon?

Tags: c#

I have this data into the test text file:

```
behzad  razzaqi  xezerlooot   abrizii         ast
```

i want delete space and replace space one semicolon character,write this code in c# for that:

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\test.txt");
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\test.txt"))
            {
                foreach (string line in allLines)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.Length > 1)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(line.Replace(" ", ";"));
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("ok");
```

```
behzad;;razzaqi;;xezerlooot;;;abrizii;;;;;ast
```

but i want one semicolon in space.how can i solve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex is an option:

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\test.txt");
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\test.txt"))
{
    foreach (string line in allLines)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.Length > 1)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(line,@"\s+",";"));
        }
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("ok");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\test.txt");
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\test.txt"))
{
     foreach (string line in allLines)
     {
          string[] words = line.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
          string joined = String.Join(";", words);
          sw.WriteLine(joined);
     }
}
```

Comment: The inner loop wouldn't actually do anything as all "word"s would be already trimmed, so the output from this code is the same as `Replace(" ", ";")`, you need to use the overload that takes `StringSplitOptions` and pass in `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a regular expression:

```
(\s\s+)
```

**Usage**

```
var input = "behzad  razzaqi  xezerlooot   abrizii         ast";
var pattern = "(\s\s+)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, ';');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a **regular expression**.

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

and:

```
  string pattern = "\\s+";
  string replacement = ";";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  sw.WriteLine(rgx.Replace(line, replacement));
```

This regular expression matches any series of 1 or more spaces and replaces the entire series with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
 Regex r=new Regex(@"\s+");

 string result=r.Replace("YourString",";");
```

`\s+` is for matching all spaces. `+` is for one or more occurrences.

for more information on `regular expression` see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should check a string length after replacement, not before ;-).

```
const string file = @"d:\test.txt";

var result = File.ReadAllLines(file).Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", ";"));

File.WriteAllLines(file, result.Where(line => line.Length > 1));
```

...and don't forget, that for input    `hello`     you will get `;hello;`.